# Unusual iostream happenings in C++?

Tags: c++, iostream

I have the following program which compiles fine and with no errors or warnings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>
#include "classes.h"

int width = 0;
int height = 0;

int init(int width = 640, int height = 480, int bpp = 32) // needs to be the first  statement called in main()

{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, bpp, SDL_OPENGL);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("SpaceInvaders", NULL);
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
}

void setstates(int width = 640, int height = 480) // needs to be called when the    window is resized
{
    ::width = width;
    ::height = height;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    setstates();
    std::cout << ::width << std::endl;
    std::cout << ::height << std::endl;

    int a ;
    std::cin >> a;

    return 0;
}
```

What I am finding curious is when I call cout in the main function and I am running the program, the console appears and displays nothing, when I press a letter and enter, the program returns 0 as if it were at the cin statement but the console will not even display the letter I have pressed.

I do however get a stdout.txt document in the compiled program directory with what is apparently the cout'ed information formatted by a newline as it is in the program.

Therefore my question is what is the problem? and why is this happening, I have never experienced it before.

Thank you for your time in advance

Comment: Are you redirecting output to a file?  For example, in the command prompt / terminal, you can type `myprogram some arguments >stdout.txt` and that will produce the behavior you describe.

Comment: No, that's what I don't understand, All I am doing is simply linking it against the appropriate libraries and nothing else.

Comment: What build system / IDE are you using?  Can you post a makefile or other build script, as well as a sample user session (e.g. the exact commands you type)?

Comment: themel's answer is correct, SDL redirects output by default, thank you for trying to help though, I should have checked with the documentation before questioning.

Comment: Have you shown your real code? The function that says it needs to be the first function called from `main` isn't called at all.

Comment: This is the real code I have so far, I hadn't gotten far into writing the code when I decided to stop and try calling cout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SDL redirects your output, as mentioned in [the FAQ](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/FAQ_Console).

Comment: But the FAQ says I/O is redirected in `SDL_Init`, and that's never actually called from the program shown here.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: You are correct - but I think it's likely that the OP omitted the init call in making the post, since the observed behaviour is precisely what SDL would do if init were called.

Comment: SDL_Init is never called whilst I am getting this problem

Comment: @Michael The FAQ seems to be wrong - output isn't redirected in SDL_Init(), but in SDL's main function which substitutes your `main` during preprocessing. You can see for yourself: http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/e044e7c70a50/src/main/win32/SDL_win32_main.c